# Sort dictionary by value in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

This is my dictionary :

```
d = {'jan': 50, 'feb': 30, 'march': 60, 'april': 50, 'may': 50, 'june': 60, 'july': 20}
```

I am expecting output like this :

```
d = {'jan': 50, 'april': 50, 'may': 50, 'march': 60, 'june': 60, 'feb': 30, 'july': 20}
```

When I run this program I am getting different output than expected :

```
d = {'jan': 50, 'feb': 30, 'march': 60, 'april': 50, 'may': 50, 'june': 60, 'july': 20}
sortlist = sorted(d, key=d.get)
print(sortlist)
```

Comment: If you want to sort by the number of duplicates, then you need to do some counting... `key=d.get` obviously isn't gonna do the trick.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a bit more information on what you are actually trying to achieve? As it stands it is very unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Looks like a job for `Counter`. Perhaps count the repeating values of the dict and then display them in desc ord

Comment: I guess you want to do these 3 things, 1: count how many times did the number appeared, 2: sort by the count, 3: if the number is the same, sort by months in the key. Correct?

Comment: @Ramani how exactly do you want your dict to be sorted ? It is not clear as to you want it to be sorted by key or value

Comment: Answered below, which should be top rated search...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 1):

You can start by counting the amount of times each value appears with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(d.values())
# Counter({20: 1, 30: 1, 50: 3, 60: 2})
```

And now sort the dictionary looking up how many times each value appears using a `key` in `sorted`:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: c[x[1]], reverse=True)
[('jan', 50), ('april', 50), ('may', 50), ('march', 60), ('june', 60), 
 ('feb', 30), ('july', 20)]
```

Note however that if you obtain a dictionary from the result, the order will not be mantained, as dictionaries have no order.

So one thing you can so is use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the order, simply call `OrderedDict(res)` on the resulting list of tuples.

Answer (score -1):

```
d={'january': 500, 'feb':600, 'march':300,'april':500,'may':500,'june':600,'july':200}

from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

count_dict = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in d.items():
  count_dict[value] += 1
```

First, we count occurences of each value. `Counter` can be used instead of `defaultdict`. Then sort them according to `count_dict` lookup table we just created.

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: count_dict[item[1]], reverse=True))
print(sorted_dict)

>>> OrderedDict([('january', 500), ('april', 500), ('may', 500), ('feb', 600), ('june', 600), ('march', 300), ('july', 200)])
```

---

**Update :** You can create `count_dict` with `Counter` like:

```
from collections import Counter

count_dict = Counter(d.values())
```